# Unable to call the fragment with imageView in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

Today is my first time to be using the fragments. And  I was able to make a simple app that utilizes the fragment, however, there is one problem that I cannot understand or hadn't noticed yet. The problem is the app crashes when I add the fragment with the imageView. Everything works fine when I use simple texts or other widgets. I've set the sample code below.

I'm calling the fragment from Activity1 like this.

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager2 = getSupportFragmentManager();

 android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction2 = fragmentManager2.beginTransaction();

   TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();

   fragmentTransaction2.add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment,"HELLO");

   fragmentTransaction2.commit();
```

This is the layout that fills the fragment

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the simple Activity2 class that extends the fragment

```
public class Activity2 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /** Inflating the layout for this fragment **/
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_class2, null);

        return v;
    }
}
```

this is the  layout for the class that extends the fragment .
Ps: The imageview in here causes the error, however, the settings in the fragment class may be the problem. I need to display the imageView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/imaew2"
        android:src="@drawable/playimage2"
 />

</LinearLayout>
```

These are the error I get and I'm not sure how these errors mean, however the error is pointing to the Fragment

at com.trymeagain.Activity2.onCreateView(Activity2.java:13)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:458)

```
Added new Error

05-07 17:56:20.701    3173-3173/com.trymeagain E/art﹕ Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 74649612 byte allocation with 1048576 free bytes and 63MB until OOM"
05-07 17:56:20.703    3173-3173/com.trymeagain D/skia﹕ --- allocation failed for scaled bitmap
05-07 17:56:20.704    3173-3173/com.trymeagain D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
05-07 17:56:20.704    3173-3173/com.trymeagain E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.trymeagain, PID: 3173
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class <unknown>
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:55)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:682)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:741)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
            at com.trymeagain.PlusOneFragment.onCreateView(Activity2.java:13)
```

Comment: What is the actual exception?

Comment: It is more of a warning. " Avoid passing null as the view root (needed to resolve layout parameters on the inflated layout's root element)" But I find it difficult to solve this null .

Comment: You said it was crashing. Can you paste the top of the stack trace?

Comment: Ok! I've added the stack trace  to the edit.

Comment: Your bitmap might be too large. What is the resolution of @drawable/playimage2 ?

Comment: width = 1080, height =1920 ........ I guess this might be the problem. What would the min and max of the images when using in android's fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you getting the exception in your imageview where your image playimage2 is too large and the heap memory is not enough to allocate ...

solution-

**case1 : if size need to increase on higher resolution device**

if playimage2 is possible to patch-then try to reduce the size of the image..you can use tool like photoshop to do so.and then patch the image

**case2 : if size need to be constant as written in xml 50dp*50dp**

Just try to reduce the size of the image